# Проверка введенного числа C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

На вход подается string число. Как произвести сравнение?

Comment: Вы объясните, что для чего Вам нужен этот код. Сравниваете строку и символьный массив ? Пытаетесь проверить их на равенство ?

Comment: Лично мне пока не понятно, зачем нам здесь вот это: ```-'0'```

Comment: Мне надо сравнить символьный массив и строку, должно выполняться строгое равентсво

Comment: Почему тогда не использовать просто условие ```arr[i] == CONST[i]``` ?

Comment: Не проще ли держать числа не как строки, а как обычные числа? К чему мучения с переводом `CONST` всякий раз? сделайте его `int`, и тогда ваш код превратится в `atoi(arr) > CONST` :)

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно следующее определение функции `Check`, как показано в демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

bool Check( const char *arr, int size, const std::string &CONST )
{
    return ( CONST.size() < size ) || 
           ( !( size < CONST.size() ) && 
              std::lexicographical_compare( CONST.begin(), CONST.end(),
                                            arr, arr + size ) );
}                                           

int main() 
{
    std::string CONST( "10" );

    const char *s = "9"; 

    std::cout << " CONST < s " << std::boolalpha << Check( s, 1, CONST ) << std::endl;

    s = "10"; 

    std::cout << " CONST < s " << std::boolalpha << Check( s, 2, CONST ) << std::endl;

    s = "11"; 

    std::cout << " CONST < s " << std::boolalpha << Check( s, 2, CONST ) << std::endl;

    s = "20"; 

    std::cout << " CONST < s " << std::boolalpha << Check( s, 2, CONST ) << std::endl;

    s = "20"; 
    CONST = std::to_string( std::numeric_limits<int>::max() );

    std::cout << " CONST < s " << std::boolalpha << Check( s, 2, CONST ) << std::endl;

    CONST = "2147483647";
    s = "2147483647";

    std::cout << " CONST < s " << std::boolalpha << Check( s, 10, CONST ) << std::endl;

    CONST = "2147483647";
    s = "2147483648";

    std::cout << " CONST < s " << std::boolalpha << Check( s, 10, CONST ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
 CONST < s false
 CONST < s false
 CONST < s true
 CONST < s true
 CONST < s false
 CONST < s false
 CONST < s true
```

Показанная функция не проверяет, содержит ли строка ведущие символы `'0'`. Поэтому в функцию надо передавть указатель на строку, начиная с позиция, которая не содержит символ `'0'`, или если строка содержит единственный символ '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Может вот? Я просто поменял больше или равно на равно в

`if(arr[i] >= CONST[i]-'0')` Проверьте. Должно сработать

```
bool Check(char *arr, int size, const string &CONST){
    bool state = false;
    if(size == CONST.size()){
        for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
            if(arr[i] > CONST[i]-'0'){
                state = true;
            }
            else{
                state = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(size > CONST.size())
        state = true;
    if(size < CONST.size())
        state = false;
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Мне надо сравнить символьный массив и строку, должно выполняться строгое равентсво

По-моему, проще всего -

```
bool equal(const char * s1, const string& s2)
{
    return strcmp(s1,s2.c_str()) == 0;
}
```